# Java 7 - LinkOption - why is NOFOLLOW_LINKS the only available option?

Tags: java, java-7, nio, symlink, linkoption

I think the title says it all. How would I specify FOLLOW_LINKS? Why create an enum with just one option? For example, the method java.nio.file.Files.getLastModifiedTime(Path, LinkOption...) takes an array of LinkOption-s as argument. You have to pass something, yet you can only pass the one option available. This surprised me, and would like to know more about it.

Comment: Of course, allowing an arbitrary number of options allows future extensions without the need to change the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following links is the default behavior.  I.e., if you don't specify NOFOLLOW_LINKS, then links are followed.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) of the `Files.getLastModifiedTime()` method (emphasis mine):

> The options array may be used to indicate how symbolic links are handled for the case that the file is a symbolic link. **By default, symbolic links are followed and the file attribute of the final target of the link is read.** If the option NOFOLLOW_LINKS is present then symbolic links are not followed.

Comment: yes, i figured so after a while looking around into other nio areas, i found "When copying a symbolic link, the target of the link is copied. If you want to copy the link itself, and not the contents of the link, specify either the NOFOLLOW_LINKS or REPLACE_EXISTING option." which explains the presence of LinkOption enum. I don't know why I have not checked the docs for Files.getLastModifiedTime() first.

Comment: It does seem like it would have been beneficial if the `LinkOption` documentation mentioned that following links is the default behavior for calls where `LinkOption` is used.

Comment: another problem is that when i looked at the javadocs for getLastModifiedTime() I didn't read the "executive summary" at the top, just jumped directly to Parameters section, and all it says there is: "options - options indicating how symbolic links are handled" And so I could not understand why my only option seems to be to NOT follow symlinks. All clear now :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What confused me a bit is that the LinkOptions argument to Files.exists() is a vararg argument , a fact I did not recognize immediately... you may just leave it away. Setting it to null will give an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the NIO.2 methods use a varargs for passing options, even when there
is only one enum value available. The advantage of this approach, as opposed to say just passing a
boolean argument, is future-proofing. These method signatures are insulated from changes in the
Java language down the road when future options are available.

cited from  "OCP Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 11 Programmer II"